# check if a CORS error is occuring using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cors, p5.js, webflow

I'm experiencing a CORS error on a website made with webflow. Basically, I wrote a p5.js script to draw some images fetched from Webflow CMS, the problem is that when I load the images through their URL I often get an error that says: "is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin".

I did some research and I couldn't find a solution to this issue, the only thing that seems to work is refreshing the page a couple of times.

So I wanted to implement a temporary solution adding a js script that refreshes the page if a CORS error happened. I've tried with this but unfortunately, even though I see the error from the console, it seems like the script is not triggered.

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

```js
window.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log("I detected this error: " + error);
  location.reload();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Webflow has wrongly configured CORS headers (see [this 4-year long discussion](https://discourse.webflow.com/t/cors-no-access-control-allow-origin/72278/22)). CORS is a browser-level security feature, so there is is no way around it from your end. Webflow must update their platform to conform to modern Internet security, or it will continue to fail more and more often as browsers expand enforcement.

However, to answer your question:
To error-catch CORS-blocked canvas drawing, you can do so at the draw command:

```js
try {
    canvasContext.drawImage( myCrossOriginImage, 0, 0 );
} catch ( e ) {
    console.error( "Caught a contaminated image, cannot draw it: ", e );
}
```

Since this error does not fire on the canvas element, it will not propagate to the window element.

Since you are using p5.js, the draw event is probably happening outside your code, so this might be difficult, but please try it at your `image()` command.

```js
try {
    image( myCrossOriginImage, 0, 0 );
} catch ( e ) {
    console.error( "Caught a contaminated image, cannot draw it: ", e );
    //instead of reloading the page, please try drawing a different image?
}
```

Comment: I've tried add the try/catch even in different positions (loading images, drawing images...) but I can't see the console.error while the CORS error is still present

Comment: Unfortunately, that probably means p5.js is executing `context.drawImage()` in a separate event loop (for example, by using requestAnimationFrame). You will not be able to catch that error without modifying p5.js.

Comment: However, I do not recommend modifying p5.js. The basic problem here is Webflow's CORS. It will be difficult to work around that in your code. Even if you fix it today, it could be broken again next week as more of Webflow goes down. Please try loading images a different way.

Comment: So I should load images outside webflow CMS, somewhere that I can access without getting CORS, right? or maybe I can rewrite the code to draw images with context.drawImage() instead of using p5.js

Comment: I would recommend loading images outside. Using context.drawImage() will still break with CORS problems, even if you can catch the error. I don't know your setup. For example, put `mypic.jpg` somewhere on your site, like `https://example.com/myapp/img/mypic.jpg`, then pass that location to `loadImage()`. Alternatively, you can [convert your entire image to a URI](https://ezgif.com/image-to-datauri). A URI works exactly like a URL, but it's _really_ long and contains the entire image data. That way, you can paste the image into your JavaScript file as text.

Comment: Which website would you recommend to upload the pictures?